ORA-00955 name is already in use
I got the error message that the name is already used by an existing object but then it still created the table.
CREATE TABLE InventoryItem (
    InventoryID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    MovieID NUMBER,
    FormatID NUMBER,
    DistributorID NUMBER,
    DistributorSN VARCHAR2(100),
    Cost NUMBER(10, 2),
    RentalPrice NUMBER(10, 2),
    FOREIGN KEY (MovieID) REFERENCES Movie(MovieID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FormatID) REFERENCES Format(FormatID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DistributorID) REFERENCES Distributor(DistributorID)
);

Not sure if I can continue creating tables or do i have to redo it.

Please update the question by full error message


I got the error message that the name is already used by an existing object but then it still created the table.

No, if you got an error message then the statement that you executed was not successful.
What you have probably found is that the table was created previously and when you ran the statement (or script) a second time it tried to create the table and failed (because it already existed) and you are then using the original version of the table.
If you have made changes to the DDL then they will not have been applied and you will need to either:

Use DROP TABLE to drop the table and re-run your CREATE TABLE statement to recreate it; or
Use ALTER TABLE to modify the existing table to apply the changes.

If the DDL statement is unchanged from the first time you ran it then you can just use the original version.

One other alternative is that the INVENTORYITEM identifier is used by a different object type; in which case you will need to rename either the original object or the new table so that they have a different identifier. (But as you claim to be able to use the table this alternative is unlikely.)

I think, you should check if the table InventoryItem was created before.
You can use this sql to check,

select * from all_tables
where table_name = 'INVENTORYITEM'

